# how to print summary data in R?

Tags: r

```
print(results)
       symptom1     disease
      Headache     Chicken pox
         Fever     Chicken pox
loss of appetite   Chicken pox
Red Color rashes   Chicken pox
         Scabs     Chicken pox
     Shivering     Malaria
         Fever     Malaria
    vomitings     Malaria
  muscle pain     Malaria
     sweating     Malaria
 table<-subset(results,symptom1=="Headache"|symptom1=="Fever"|symptom1=="Scrabs")
 > print(table)
 symptom1     disease
1 Headache Chicken pox
2    Fever Chicken pox
7    Fever     Malaria
> summary(table)
              symptom1        disease 
    Fever           :2   Chicken pox:2  
    Headache        :1   Malaria    :1  
    loss of appetite:0                  
    muscle pain     :0                  
    Red Color rashes:0                 
      Scabs           :0                  
      (Other)         :0
```

how do i print value Chicken pox. I want to print disease with more value in summary(table)
In this case chickenpox
i hope my question is clear.
thank u in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
table %>% 
  group_by(disease) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(n==max(n)) %>%
  select(-n)
```

Comment: it works great when simply coding in R. But it doesnot work with rserve-js and Rserve when it is in this form client.eval("result %>%", function(err, response). can u please guide me to make this code work with rserve-js and Rserve.

Comment: @dpak Could you please post that as a new question as the `rserve-js` and `Rserve` are different

Comment: ok.i have posted from @naruto. if u have the idea please guide me. thanks